# footer se sube a la mitad de la pagina en el celular

Tags: html, css

Mi problema es el siguiente cuando abro mi proyecto web le doy a inpeccionar y lo pongo en modo movil el footer esta correctamente al final de la pagina. Pero cuando abro con mi celular se coloca a la mitad de la pagina.
Yo lo que estoy haciendo para que este debajo es en css .

```
  body{
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
    
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
   }
```

Y el footer

```
.footer{

  margin-top: 4rem;
  align-self: flex-end;

  height: 10rem;
  width: 100%;


  background-color: rgb(46, 48, 47);
}
```

Esta es la pagina si la abres desde la computadora el footer se ve perfecto el tema es desde el celular: https://angry-feynman-da7262.netlify.app/

Comment: Necesitamos mas información para entender  el porque del comportamiento, puedes publicar un zip del sitio o mas información de su código?

Comment: Puedes agregar todo el codigo, html, y css acá y pasarlo a snippet

Comment: CTRL M funciona en el editor para abrir

Comment: No se como puedo subir un zip aqui no veo la opcion.Y lo otro si agrego todo el codigo me dice que tengo que poner mas descripcion sobre el problema

Answer (score 0):

utiliza la propiedad position fixed esto te permite agregar la posición bottom que deberás colocar en 0 para que se valla al fondo.

Referencia: [How TO - Fixed Footer](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp)

[image: Vista movil]

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

tengo

Comment: El problema de esa solucion es que te quedea abajo pero no de la pagina web es como que si hago scroll para arriba el footer tambien sube

Comment: Es correcto, en tu caso en vez de fixed te serviria mejor absolute, sin embargo, ingrese al enlace de tu respuesta y no pude replicar el problema del footer, ya lo resolviste?